# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{x\cos{x}}{1+\sin^{2}{x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Integrate
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{x\cos{x}}{1+\sin^{2}{x}}dx}$$

Comment: Hint: let t=sinx.

Comment: Why was this marked as duplicate? The other integral, although similar in appearance, is not the same creature at all: the techniques used on that page can't be applied to this one.

Comment: @L.F. I believe using $t=\frac\pi2-x$ you will get the other integral.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It doesn't though: that subsitution yields the other integral, but with altered bounds.

Comment: @L.F. If I'm not mistaken, you'll get something like $\frac\pi2 \int \frac{\sin t}{1+\cos^2 t} - \int \frac{t\sin t}{1+\cos^2 t}$ after this substitution.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Precisely - but both of those are taken on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, not $(0,\pi)$. The first is clearly $0$. The second on the other hand...

Comment: @L.F. Sorry, I missed the problem with the range.

Comment: I was writing up a solution when this post was wrongly marked as duplicate. This integral is not related to that other integral.

Comment: What's the recourse when a thread is incorrectly marked as duplicate?

Comment: @RandomVariable You can write a request in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-votes).

Comment: From comments above, it seems, this problem has more elementary solutions without the dilogarithm and legendre chi function. It would be better, if you answer those  solutions than just mention in comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With some calculations, we obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x \cos x}{1+\sin^2 x} \, dx = 4 \chi_{2}(1-\sqrt{2})$$

where

$$ \chi_{2}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2} $$

is the [Legendre chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function) of order 2. By exploiting some identities involving dilogarithm, we find that

$$ \chi_{2}(1-\sqrt{2}) = \frac{1}{4} \log^2 (1+\sqrt{2}) - \frac{3}{8}\zeta(2). $$

This gives the answer

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x \cos x}{1+\sin^2 x} \, dx = \log^2(1+\sqrt{2}) - \frac{\pi^2}{4}. $$

Some detailed calculations, though written in Korean, can be found in [my blog posting](http://sos440.tistory.com/83).

Comment: Very Nice solution,thank you very much! sos440

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont get the first step. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more elementary way:$$J=\int_0^\pi\frac{x \cos(x) dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}= \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x \cos(x)dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{-x \sin(x)dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}-\frac{\pi}{2} \int_\frac{\pi}{2}^0 \frac{- \sin (x) dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}$$
$$J=I_1-I_2-\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

---

$$I_1=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{ x\cos(x) dx}{1+\sin^2(x)}= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \cos(x) \sin^{2k}(x)dx$$
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2k+1}- \frac{1}{2k+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^{2k+1}(x) dx \right)$$
, using the beta function,
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2k+1}- \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(k+1+\frac{1}{2})} \right)$$
, and the Legendre duplication formula,
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2k+1}- \frac{1}{2k+1}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)^22^{2k+1}}{\Gamma(2k+2)} \right)$$
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2k+1}- \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\frac{2^{2k+1}}{\binom{2k}{k}} \right)$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{2}\arctan(1)-\sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k  \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\frac{2^{2k+1}}{\binom{2k}{k}} $$

$$\stackrel{\text{Mathematica}}{=} \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}+ \frac{1}{2}\sinh^{-1}(1)^2 $$

$$I_1= \frac{1}{2}\sinh^{-1}(1)^2 $$

---

$$I_2=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{ x\sin(x) dx}{1+\cos^2(x)}= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \sin(x) \cos^{2k}(x)dx$$
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \frac{1}{2k+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}   \cos^{2k+1}(x)dx$$
$$= \sum_{k \ge 0}(-1)^k \frac{1}{2k+1}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}   \sin^{2k+1}(x)dx$$
$$I_2=\frac{\pi^2}{8}- \frac{1}{2} \sinh^{-1}(1)^2$$

---

Thus

$$J=\sinh^{-1}(1)^2- \frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

Comment: The *Mathematica* result follows from the fact that $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2\displaystyle{2n\choose n}} ~=~ 2\arcsin^2x.~$