# Integrating $\int_0^\pi \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, closed-form

I am working on $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx$

First: I use integrating by part then get

$$ x\arctan(\sin x)\Big|_0^\pi-\int_0^\pi \arctan(\sin x)\,dx $$

then I have $\displaystyle -\int_0^\pi \arctan(\sin x)\,dx$ because $x\arctan(\sin x)\Big|_0^\pi$ is equal to $0$

However, I don't know how to integrate $\displaystyle -\int_0^\pi \arctan(\sin x)\,dx$

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: I recall this to be a challenging integral that can be solved with some help of dilogarithms. The answer is $$\log^2(1+\sqrt{2})-\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Comment: @HansLundmark ??? The question aren't the same at all. This feature is for *exact* duplicates. Going from the integral to the sum is not completely trivial.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi here are *two exact* duplicates. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296548/i-need-assistance-in-integrating-fracx-sin-x1-cos-x2 
and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323603/integrate-displaystyle-int-0-pi-fracx-cosx1-sin2xdx?rq=1

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Then you can vote to close the question as duplicate of these, not the other one...

Comment: I wish to register my disagreement with the duplicate labeling.  The problem statements are completely different and are only related through an integration by parts, and that is being generous.  If we were to label every integral on this site as being a duplicate of another related via integration by parts, then we have our work cut out for us.  Further, the solution I offer was motivated by the statement of this particular problem, and is not shown in the other problem.

Comment: I have reopened the question.  If this question is a duplicate of the other marked question, then there are a lot more questions on this site that are duplicates.  And I don't think anyone wants to go there.  I sure don't.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Only the second of those two are a duplicate. The first one is much simpler.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: If people want to keep this question open, I'm not going to argue. I just thought that this question (even if phrased differently) was actually answered elsewhere, and that's it's unnecessary to give the same answers again...

Answer (score 18):

I will outline how this problem may be attacked using complex analysis.  This is a surprisingly involved problem which I mistook for a much easier one in which the sines and cosines were reversed.  But this is again a useful exercise in setting up a contour integral and applying the residue theorem.  It is very satisfying to see that the correct result appears after all the analysis and manipulation.

First recognize that

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} = \left [\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} \int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}}\right ]_{\alpha=1}$$

The idea is to somehow stretch the integration interval over the unit circle.  If we instead consider the integral

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2 \pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} &= \int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}}+\int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} \\ &= (1+\cos{\pi \alpha}) \int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}}+\sin{\pi \alpha} \int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\cos{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}}\end{align}$$

Note that the second integral on the RHS may be extended over $[-\pi,\pi]$ due to the evenness of the integrand.

We now have the desired integral expressed in terms of two integrals that now may be expressed in terms of an integral over the unit circle in the complex plane.

We consider the following integral:

$$i 4 \oint_{C_{\pm}} dz \frac{z^{1+\alpha}}{z^4-6 z^2+1} $$

where $C_{\pm}$ is a keyhole contour about the positive/negative real axis, traversing the unit circle counterclockwise, with semicircular detours about the respective poles about $\pm (\sqrt{2}-1)$.  (For a similar setup, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633282/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-fracx21-cos2-xdx/634577#634577).)

For example, $C_-$ is the following contour

[image: crazy keyhole]

which is a modified keyhole contour about the negative real axis within the unit circle.  The modification is a pair of semicircular bumps of radius $\epsilon$ about the point $z=-1+\sqrt{2}$.  These bumps are necessary because the integrand has a pole within the unit circle on the chosen branch cut of the integrand (i.e., the negative real axis).

I will leave the parametrization of the contour integral to the reader for the time being.  Using the residue theorem, we determine that

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\sin{\alpha x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} = \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{2}} \left (\sqrt{2}-1 \right )^{\alpha} \sin{\pi \alpha} - 8 \sin^2{\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}} PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1}$$

Taking the derivative and setting $\alpha=1$ on both sides, we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} = -\frac12 \left (1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right )\pi^2 - 8 PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^2 \log{x}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} $$

Now,

$$\frac{8 x^2}{x^4-6 x^2+1} = \left (1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left (\frac1{x-(\sqrt{2}+1)}- \frac1{x+(\sqrt{2}+1)}\right ) \\ - \left (1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left (\frac1{x-(\sqrt{2}-1)}- \frac1{x+(\sqrt{2}-1)}\right )$$

The integrals individually may be expressed in terms of polylogs:

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{x-(\sqrt{2}+1)} = \operatorname{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)} $$
$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{x+(\sqrt{2}+1)} = \operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}-1))} $$

$$PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{x-(\sqrt{2}-1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{3} - \frac12 \log^2{(1+\sqrt{2})}- \operatorname{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)} $$

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{\log{x}}{x+(\sqrt{2}-1)} = \operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}+1))} $$

Then

$$ 8 PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^2 \log{x}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} = \left (1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left [\operatorname{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)}- \operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}-1))}\right ]\\ - \left (1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left [\frac{\pi^2}{3} - \frac12 \log^2{(1+\sqrt{2})}- \operatorname{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}+1))} \right ] $$

We apply the [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) [identities](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~dduke/devoto-duke-84.pdf) for $z \lt 0$ and $0 \lt z \lt 1$ respectively:

$$\operatorname{Li}_2{(z)} + \operatorname{Li}_2{\left(\frac1{z}\right )} = -\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac12 \log^2{(-z)} $$

$$\operatorname{Li}_2{\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right )} - \operatorname{Li}_2{\left(-\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right )} = \operatorname{Li}_2{(-z)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{(z)} + \frac{\pi^2}{4} + \log{z} \log{\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right )}$$

In the first identity, let $z=-(\sqrt{2}-1)$; in the second identity, let $z=\sqrt{2}-1$.  For the latter case, it is fortuitous that $z=(1-z)/(1+z)$.  We get

$$\operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}-1))}+\operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}+1))}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac12 \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)} $$

$$\operatorname{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)}-\operatorname{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}-1))} = \frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac12 \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)} $$

We may now start putting this altogether:

$$ 8 PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^2 \log{x}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} = \left (1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left [\frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac12 \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)}\right ]\\ - \left (1-\frac1{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \left [\frac{9 \pi^2}{24} + \frac12 \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)} \right ] $$

With just a little more arithmetic, we may finally conclude that

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} = \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)} - \frac{\pi^2}{4} $$

**ADDENDUM**

I will provide detail as to the evaluation of the contour integral by the residue theorem.  Again, consider the above contour integral:

$$i 4 \oint_{C_-} dz \frac{z^{1+\alpha}}{z^4-6 z^2+1} $$

As one may see from the figure, this contour has 8 segments, the integrals over which I will now write out in detail.  Let $z_0=\sqrt{2}-1$.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\phi \frac{e^{i \alpha \phi}}{1+\sin^2{\phi}} + i 4 e^{i \pi \alpha} \int_1^{z_0+\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} \\ -4 \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(e^{i \pi} z_0 + \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{1+\alpha}}{ (-z_0+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^4– 6 (-z_0+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2 + 1} + i 4 e^{i \pi \alpha} \int_{z_0-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} \\  - 4 \epsilon \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{\epsilon^{1+\alpha} e^{i (1+\alpha) \phi}}{\epsilon^4 e^{i 4 \phi} – 6 \epsilon^2 e^{i 2 \phi}+1} + i 4 e^{-i \pi \alpha} \int_{\epsilon}^{z_0-\epsilon} dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} \\ -4 \epsilon \int_0^{-\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{(e^{-i \pi} z_0 + \epsilon e^{i \phi})^{1+\alpha}}{ (-z_0+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^4– 6 (-z_0+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2 + 1} + i 4 e^{-i \pi \alpha} \int_{z_0+\epsilon}^{1} dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1}$$

which is equal to, in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\phi \frac{e^{i \alpha \phi}}{1+\sin^2{\phi}}  + i 4 e^{i \pi \alpha} PV \int_1^0 dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} \\ + i 4 e^{-i \pi \alpha} PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1} - \frac{\pi z_0^{\alpha}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \left (e^{i \pi \alpha} + e^{-i \pi \alpha} \right ) $$

The contour integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=\sqrt{2}-1$, or $2 \pi z_0^{\alpha}/(2 \sqrt{2}) e^{i \pi \alpha}$.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\phi \frac{\cos{\alpha \phi}}{1+\sin^2{\phi}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} z_0^{\alpha} (1+\cos{\pi \alpha}) – 8 \sin{\pi \alpha} \, PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1}$$

Using the contour $C_+$, we can find the value of the other integral:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \frac{\sin{\alpha \phi}}{1+\sin^2{\phi}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} z_0^{\alpha} \sin{\pi \alpha} (1+\cos{\pi \alpha}) – 8 \sin^2{\pi \alpha} \, PV \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{1+\alpha}}{x^4-6 x^2+1}$$

The result follows.

Comment: @Ron Gordon Thank you for sharing the link 'identities'! I had forgotten it! +1. I just gave another approach for the above integral.

Answer (score 10):

Split the integral at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, we get

$\displaystyle \begin{align} \int_0^\pi \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx &= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx \\ & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx - \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(x+\pi/2)\sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}\,dx \\ &= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx - \pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx  \\ &= 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx - \frac{\pi^2}{4}\end{align}$

At this point we can write the above integral:

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{8} - \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^{-1} \sin x \,dx$

The later can be evaluated in many ways. See for example [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048045).

See integral representations of [Legendre $\chi$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function).

Also sos440 [**blog**](http://sos440.tistory.com/83) entry has a very nice solution to the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Let be

$$\begin{align} I=\int_0^\pi \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\operatorname{d}x&=-\int_0^\pi \arctan(\sin x)\operatorname{d}x \\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/2} \arctan(\sin x)\operatorname{d}x\\
&=-2\int_0^1\frac{\arctan t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\operatorname{d}t
\end{align}$$
Let $$ \displaystyle I(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan at}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \ dt.$$

Differentiating under the integral,

$$ \begin{align}  I'(a) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{(1+a^{2}t^{2})\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \ dt \\ &=  \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \text{arctanh} \left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \right)\\ 
&= \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \text{arcsinh}(a) . 
\end{align}$$

Integrating back,

$$ \begin{align} I(1)-I(0) = I(1) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(a)}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \ da \\ &= - \text{arcsinh}(a) \text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a}) \Big|^{1}_{0} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \ da \\ &= - \text{arcsinh}^{2}(1) +  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \ da \\ &= - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \ da . \end{align}$$

Now let $ \displaystyle w = \frac{1}{a}$.

Then

$$ I(1) = - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}}$$

$$ =  - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + I(\infty) - I(1) .$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} I(1) &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{I(\infty)}{2} \\ &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \ dt \\ &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} . \end{align}$$

Finally
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^\pi \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}\operatorname{d}x=-2I(1)=\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})-\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}.}$$

Comment: (+1) but I think this is *very* similar to what RV did [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/856419/129017).

Comment: Very nicely done! +1

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach.

The idea, in order to evaluate
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} {\rm d}x ,
$$
is to start with a Fourier series expansion of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\sin^2{x}} $.

For $0\leq x \leq\pi$, we easily obtain

$$\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{1+\sin^2{x}} &= \Re \frac{1}{1-i\sin{x}}\\\\
&=  \Re \frac{2e^{ix}}{2-(e^{ix}-1)^2}\\\\
 &=  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^n(1+(-1)^n)\cos (nx) \tag2
\end{align}
$$
The series in $(2)$ is normally convergent on $[0,\pi]$, we are then allowed to integrate termwise:
$$
\int_0^{\pi}\frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} {\rm d}x =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\sqrt{2}-1)^n(1+(-1)^n)\!\!\int_0^{\pi}\!\! x\cos{x}\cos (nx)x \:{\rm d}x. \tag3
$$
The latter integral is classic, we write $$ 2\cos{x}\cos (nx)=\cos((n+1)x)+\cos((n-1)x)$$ then integrate twice by parts to get
$$
-2\int_0^{\pi} x\cos{x}\cos (nx)x \:{\rm d}x=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2},\quad n=2,3,\ldots. \tag4
$$
It is easy to see that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(1+(-1)^n)\left(\frac{x^n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{x^n}{(n-1)^2}\right)=\left(x+\frac1x\right)\left({\rm{Li}}_2(x)-{\rm{Li}}_2(-x)\right), \quad |x|<1,
$$ where ${\rm{Li}}_2(\cdot)$ is the [dilogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).
Now, putting $x:= \sqrt{2}-1$ in the preceding identity and using the following closed form  $$\rm{Li}_2{(\sqrt{2}-1)}-\rm{Li}_2{(-(\sqrt{2}-1))} = \frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac12 \log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)}, \tag5$$ as previously explaned by Ron Gordon, gives easily

> $$
> \int_0^{\pi}\frac{x \cos{x}}{1+\sin^2{x}} {\rm d}x =\log^2{(\sqrt{2}+1)}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}.
> $$

Comment: Thanks for the credit.  I should say that I always enjoy reading your answers, epitomes of simplicity, erudition, and cleverness.